# Regarding outer functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Please see the definition of Hardy spaces on the unit disc [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586370/if-a-function-belongs-to-the-hardy-space). Let $0<p\leq\infty$. Let $f\in H^p$ with $\|f-1_e\|_p<1$ (Where $1_e$ Is the constant function one). Then is $f$ an **outer function**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for $p=\infty$, but is not true for $p=2$. Let $g$ be an inner function. Then, the optimal polynomial approximant $p_{n}^*$ when minimizing $\|pg-1\|_{2}$ over degree $n$ polynomials, $p$, satisfies $\|p_{n}^{*}g-1\|_{2}^2=1-|g(0)|^2$ (see http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~dkhavins/files/GenInnerFinal.pdf, pg. 6, for details).

To answer your question it suffices then to look at $g$ inner (and not also outer) with $|g(0)|>0$, since $f=p_{n}^{*}g$ need not be outer.